# 0x80070057 error when installing windows 8 app

Tags: windows, windows-8

When installing Windows 8 app, i got the below exception. Does anyone have any clue as to what the error may entail? I would post this on windows forum as well, but apparently the board is down as I am typing this.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: That seems to be a very generic error, thrown by everything from Windows Setup to failure during backup, file transfer etc.